# How do I make an app part I developed available in About Me or Newsfeed?

Tags: 2013, web-part, sharepoint-addin, app-part

I have developed a SharePoint autohosted app using VS2013. I have been able to successfully get it deployed to my Office 365 based SharePoint. The app has an app part included and I have been able to insert that app part into pages of the sites in my SharePoint.

What I would like to do is add this app part to the NewsFeed or About Me pages. However, when I go to "Edit Page" under the Gear icon for those pages and then select "Add a Web Part" my app part is not visible as being available. On normal pages, my app part is at the top of the list and I can add it without any issues.  It looks like the list of available web parts for these pages is completely different.

Is there a special way to get app parts visible for adding to About Me/Newsfeed pages in SharePoint?

Comment: Have you deployed the app to that site collection?

Answer (score 1):

An admin needs to go to navigate to the newsfeed root site collection, click on site contents and add you app, then add the part to the page by editing it; the change will apply to ALL my sites.